# Stream 'data' event callback to push in an array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm trying to push some data chunk read from my stream in a Buffer array, like this:

```
const chunks = [];
readableStream.on('data', chunks.push);
```

But then, `chunks` is empty.

The following works well but I'd like to find the difference between those two:

```
const chunks = [];
readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
```

BTW, I'm using Node 6.2.2. Thank you

**EDIT**: I'm realizing there should be some context issue on the first line but explanations are welcome! Also, is there any recommandations/good practice on that?

Answer (score 0):

In this line :

```
readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
```

it is used a `callback` function that takes every item(`chunk`) and `added` it in `chunks` array, using `push` method.

The method is equivalent to :

```
const chunks = [];
readableStream.on('data',callback);
function callback(chunk){
     chunks.push(chunk);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but my question is why the first line is failing.

Comment: Because `readableStrem` function takes as second parameter a callback function.

Comment: `chunk.push` is a function with the same signature than `callback` and should act the same

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that methods are a different language construct than functions. `Array.prototype.push` is a method. For what you're trying to do, you could do:

```js
const chunks = [];
readableStream.on('data', chunks.push.bind(chunks));
```

`bind` here simply returns a new function object. The value of `this` within the function body is assigned to `array`. More info in [this amazing answer on how `this` works in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/9906706) (see the two sections about functions and function properties).

Answer (score 0):

1. [].push equal to Array.prototype.push, it losts the context. You should use bind function to set context.
2. the **on** function just register your callback function. The 'data' event will be called async soon. So you can't get the value from array after **on** function.

It works for me:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const stream = fs.createReadStream("./demo.txt");
let r = [];
stream.on('data', r.push.bind(r));
console.info('empty array:', r);
setTimeout(()=>console.log('get result:', r), 1000);
```